# Chrome offers "Typed history" from another browser in address bar

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, history, vivaldi

Google Chrome shows "Typed History" in its address bar as if it was written in Chrome itself, however, the information is stolen from another browser (Vivaldi).

Example:

1. I write "hello world" in Vivaldi's address bar.
2. I switch to Chrome and click into the empty address bar.
3. Chrome offers "hello world" as the first result.

This happened very recently after reinstall of Windows (and both browsers), so I suspect it must be a new feature of Chrome.

Additional info:

- Neither of the browsers is logged in.
- Neither of the browsers use history (or any other kind of) synchronization.
- Both browsers are chromium based.
- Only Chrome steals history (Vivaldi does not steal Chrome's history).
- History from Edge (also chromium based) is not visible in Chrome.
- Both browsers are at their current versions:

  - Chrome: 120.0.6099.130 (Offizieller Build) (64-Bit) (cohort: M120 Rollout)
  - Vivaldi: 6.5.3206.42 (Stable channel) (64-bit)

This is a privacy violation as I use Vivaldi for personal stuff and Chrome for work stuff. The strict separation of browsers is important for me, as I don't want to reveal personal browsing habits when sharing a screen in a work meeting.

I have searched Chrome's settings and chrome://flags, but I could not find anything relevant.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Google as search engine ? - If so, do you have the same behavior with another search engine like DuckDuckGo [here](https://duckduckgo.com/). Google is known for tracking searches (certainly also against IP). - Your request is legit and understandable but if you want privacy, do not use Google.